# Read word from file into simple linked list

Tags: c, pointers, file-io, linked-list

I need to write a program to read from a file, then save the words into a linked list for further use. I decided to read the text character by character using fgetc, then save all into the list each time a newline (`'\n'`) or space (`' '`) is detected, indicating one word. 
Sorry I'm a newbie in file pointers, this is what I've gotten so far:

```
struct list { //global
char string[30];
struct list *next;
};


int main(void) {

    FILE *filePtr;
    char file[] = "text.txt";
    char tempStr[30];
    list *curr, *header;
    char c;
    int i = 0;
    curr = NULL;
    header = NULL;

    if((filePtr = fopen(file, "r")) == NULL) {
        printf("\nError opening file!");
        getchar();
        exit(101);
    }
    printf("\nFile is opened for reading.\n");

    while(!EOF) {
        while((c = fgetc(filePtr) != ' ') && (c = fgetc(filePtr) != '\n')) {
            curr = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
            //c = fgetc(filePtr);
            tempStr[i] = fgetc(filePtr);
            i++;
            }

        tempStr[i] = '\0';

        strcpy(curr->string, tempStr);
        curr->next = header;
        header = curr;

        i = 0;
    }

    while(curr!=NULL) {
        printf("%s - ", curr->string); //This will not print.
        curr = curr->next;
    }

    if(fclose(filePtr) ==  EOF) {
        printf("\nError closing file!");
        getchar();
        exit(102);
    }
    printf("\nFile is closed.\n");

    getchar();
    getchar();

}
```

If the text file:

```
have a nice day
```

Desired output:

```
have - a - nice - day
```

But, I could not print out anything except the file opened and closed.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Value of the macro `EOF` is `-1`, which is a system macro defined in `stdio.h`. File read APIs(`fgetc`, `fread`, `fscanf`) will return -1 once it reaches end of file. So in your program you have `while(!EOF)` this will be always false, because `NOT` of `-1` is always 0. `-1` will be represented in 2's complement so all bits of that variable will be 1. (If size of `int` is 2, `-1` will be stored as `0xFFFF` in `int` variable).

Use the below sample code.

```
while(EOF != (c = fgetc(filePtr))) 
{

    if ((c == ' ') || (c == '\n'))
    {
        if (i == 0)
        {
            continue;
        }

        tempStr[i] = '\0';
        i = 0;

        //here do your linklist node creation and insertion operation

           continue;
    }

    tempStr[i] = c;
    i++;
}
```

Comment: Will do, Thank you very much, the code is working now. The only problem is each time i printf the word will be reversed such as from file: 'june 2012' will result in output: '2102 enuj'. i tried editing the order of my struct header and temp but still doesnt seem to work.
:(

Answer (score 0):

- This is always false:

  ```
  while(!EOF)
  ```
- Review your memory allocation code.

  ```
  curr = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list))
  ```
- Files may not have newlines at the end of the file.

  ```
  while((c = fgetc(filePtr) != ' ') && (c = fgetc(filePtr) != '\n'))
  ```

Answer (score 0):

```
while(!EOF) {
```

This is a constant condition that is always false, so you never read anything.

Your code also has other problems, such as doing

```
curr = (list*)malloc(sizeof(list));
```

in a loop but using curr outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

You should replace the while condition with whatever function you're using to read the file - are you sure fgets isn't horrendously more efficient than this?

IE read the string into a much larger buffer than you expect, then copy it into an appropriately sized buffer and attach that to the node.

Answer (score 0):

Spoiler:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct list {
    struct list *next;
    char string[30];
    };

int main(void) {

    FILE *fp;
    char file[] = "llist4.c";
     /* in C you CANNOT omit the "struct keyword" from a declaration or definition. */
    struct list *head=NULL, **pp= &head;
    int ch; /* getc() returns an int */
    size_t len ;
    char buff[30];

    fp = fopen(file, "r");
    if (!fp) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError opening file!");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nFile has been opened for reading.\n");

    for (len=0; len < sizeof buff;   ) {
        ch = fgetc(fp);
        if (ch == EOF && !len) break;
        if (ch == ' ' || ch ==  '\n' || ch == EOF) {
            if (!len) continue;
            buff[len] = '\0';
            *pp = malloc(sizeof **pp);
            if (!*pp) break;
            strcpy((*pp)->string, buff);
            (*pp)->next = NULL;
            pp = &(*pp)->next ;
            len=0; continue;
            }

        buff[len++] = ch;
    }

    if (len) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nWord was too large, or out of memory\n");
        }

    for( ;head; head= head->next) {
        printf("%s - ", head->string);
    }

    if (fclose(fp) ==  EOF) {
        fprintf(stderr, "\nError closing file!\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("\nFile has been closed.\n");
exit(EXIT_SUCCESS);
}
```